# How to translate HTTP term "Inline disposition" into Russian language?

Tags: перевод, информатика

I'm trying to translate into Russian language English term "Inline disposition" used in Internet communications. "Inline disposition" means that the file has to be shown directly in browser, not as attachment. And I can not find any close equivalent... Please help :) 
В Интернете ничего не могу найти...

I think it could be "«Инлайн» диспозиция" or "«Инлайн» размещение". But is "инлайн" word used in Russian language?

A little info about "Inline disposition":

> For example, if you have a PDF file and Firefox/Adobe Reader, an
>   inline disposition will open the PDF within Firefox, whereas
>   attachment will force it to download.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Russian.SE! When asking for translation please provide as much context as possible. A couple of usage examples would come very handy. Not all of us are software developers, so explaining what exactly do you mean by "file has to be shown directly in browser, not as attachment" in layman's terms would also have been nice. Thanks!

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395151/content-dispositionwhat-are-the-differences-between-inline-and-attachment) is the link with simple answers about file inline disposition versus attachment. I think correct answer would be very helpful for others too.

Comment: would you mind copying relevant portions of that post to your question and add a couple of usage examples you're after, please? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think word "инлайн" is used in Russian (at least I haven't heard this word). You could try something like "встроенный файл".

Comment: _Встроенное расположение_ should work, but why do you need it translated in the first place?

Comment: @ErnestasGruodis: could you please provide a Russian phrase where you would have used the translated term? Thanks!

Comment: I'm developing multi-language application, and there is a checkbox named in English "Inline disposition". So the user have to tick it or not. Thanks for answers indeed!

Comment: Why not make it "open" and "save" instead of "inline" and "attachment"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we use good old calquing, we'll have *встроенное размещение содержимого* and *размещение содержимого во вложении* for "inline content disposition" and "attachment content disposition", respectively

This concept has apparently been taken from the email standards and originally said whether you should show a picture or a rich text snippet as a whole in the email body window or just as a filename in the attachments bar with a paper clip next to it.

This does not translate for browsers very well, even in English: a downloadable file is hardly an "attachment", or a PDF which opens in a new tab is hardly "inline"; and there is no envelope for the content to have "disposition" in it.

Those are just historical header names and values which had been reused for something completely different.

So my take on this would be just leaving the English terms as is:

> При передаче данных сервер указывает способ обработки содержимого: "инлайн", если его нужно открыть в браузере, или "аттачмент", если его нужно сохранить в файл на диске.

or giving them a meaningful description, disregarding their English meanings:

> При передаче данных сервер сообщает, являются ли они *отображаемыми* или *сохраняемыми* путём установки значения заголовка `Content-Disposition` в `inline` или `attachment`, соответственно.

Again, you can't translate without a context, so if you want a useful answer, it would have been best if you provided a Russian phrase you are trying to build.

Answer (score 2):

Well, formally this could be translated as "встраиваемое/встроенное расположение/размещение". The word inline in case it is even translated is `встроенный` or `встраиваемый`. But the thing is the actually in real life scenarios nobody translate it, de-facto Russian developer or engineer will just say `инлайн` or `заинлайненный`. Actually, we can claim that the `заинлайненный` word is a new Russian word, just like we have `юзер` for computer users but `пользователь` is not gone as well, or `киллер` and `убийца`.

With disposition it is even more trickier. I bet there's no way you'll hear anything but "disposition" (диспозишн) - no developer will say "размещение". Talking, for instance, of "Content-Disposition" http header no one even attempts to translate this term.

Though, the word disposition sometimes is translated as `диспозиция` - unlike the word `заинлайненный`, this word already existed in Russian, it's just that it is used in a new way.

Even in technical documentation I guess it will probably just won't be translated in order not to confuse reader.